# How to use an entire Java project inside another Java project and instantiate and use classes and methods?

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-assembly-plugin

I came out with a situation i have a maven proyect with several clases and methods... and i need to have the same project classes and methods across some other projects that needs them.

After reading some about Git submodules, and Git Subtrees, and other ways to acomplish this. what i decided was to export a Jar file with its dependencies, and copy it to all other projects in the '${basedir}/lib/' subdirectory. This way i keep it simple enough for all the devs in my QA team (we are not SO much experienced devs, as we came from QA world) and also i can control that all of them use the same libs in all projects.

I exported to Jar file with the assembly maven plugin, adding this to my POM file in the first repo:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

And running

```
$ mvn clean compile assembly:single
```

I have the Jar file in the 'target' directory which i copied to all other repos. in the 'lib' directory of each repo.

Then in the POM files of the other repos i added to their POMs dependencies section:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>myDep</groupId>
    <artifactId>myDep</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/myDep-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

The thing is that i could not figure it out how to import the Jar in my classes to use the methods i need from this imported Jar. As i tried to import like

```
import myDep.*
```

But its not working.

Could you point me in the right direction? thank you so much!

Comment: Perhaps you need the [multiple modules](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) feature of Maven.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, before you start using Maven, you set up some infrastructure:

1. a Nexus or Artifactory server for the artifacts (jars, wars etc.)
2. a build server like Jenkins.

Then you build your jars (without anything like maven assembly plugin) on the Jenkins with `mvn clean deploy`. Then they are avaible in the Nexus/Artifactory.

If the developers have a `settings.xml` pointing to the right Nexus/Artifactory, they can then just add

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>myDep</groupId>
    <artifactId>myDep</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

to their `pom.xml` without specifying any path or copying anything around. Maven will then do the magic to resolve that dependency from Nexus/Artifactory.

Comment: In our situation, we are using only Jenkins, and not like a CD/CI tool but more like a 'Running automation tests with Cron' tool, right now. And we are more on like 'on our own' to learn and with limited develop knowledge and time. So what we needed to 'keep running' was to use this project inside another one only as a workaround to have the same utils classes repeated across several testing code repos

Comment: So, do you get your external dependencies directly from MavenCentral?

Comment: Another "pragmatic" solution would be that everybody that uses the library checks out the code from git and runs `mvn clean install` on it. Then any other project on the same account can just reference the library without copying it or using a systempath.